# Attach android:actionLayout on res/menu-how to invoke it from .xml to .java

Tags: java, android, xml

I'm a bit confused about res/menu.xml folder.

I want a cart on my action bar having textview counter(which will increment on every click). I have a  RelativeLayout that contains an ImageView and TextView named `badge_counter_text`. I want to attach it on res/menu/main.xml
which is:

```
<item
        android:id="@+id/rightSlider"
        android:orderInCategory="100"
        android:actionLayout="@layout/badge_counter_text"
        android:showAsAction="always"
        android:actionViewClass="android.widget.ImageButton"
        android:icon="@drawable/cart"
        android:title="Cart"/>
```

my badge_counter_text.xml

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/badge_layout_cartCounter"
    android:layout_width="48dp"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="right" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/add_item_counter"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_marginRight="15dp"
        android:textAppearance="@android:style/TextAppearance.Small"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/imageView1"
        android:background="@android:color/holo_red_dark"
        android:hint="0"
        android:textColor="@color/white" />

    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/imageOfCart"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:clickable="true"
        android:src="@drawable/cart" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

MY CODE:

```
@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(final Menu menu) {

    MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
    inflater.inflate(R.menu.main, menu);

    btnCart = (ImageButton)menu.findItem(R.id.rightSlider).getActionView();
    txtCount = (TextView)menu.findItem(R.id.badge_layout_cartCounter).getActionView().findViewById(R.id.add_item_counter);

    //...
}
```

The problem is I'm getting null on my `txtCount` object.

Comment: sorry i forget some.Actually i need a correct code of java cause i am getting error on above java code .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to use [Toolbar](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/Toolbar.html)
 for this purpose. You can add your own layout like this

```
<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
android:id="@+id/nav_toolbar"
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:background="@color/blue">

<ImageButton
    android:id="@+id/btn_toolbar_back"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="left"
    android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/spacing_tiny"
    android:background="@drawable/filter_nav_prev"/>

<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="center">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/toolbar_label"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:textAllCaps="false"
        android:textColor="@color/background_white"
        android:textSize="@dimen/font_big"/>
</RelativeLayout>
```

or try this code for action bar

```
ActionBar mActionBar = getActionBar();
    mActionBar.setDisplayShowHomeEnabled(false);
    mActionBar.setDisplayShowTitleEnabled(false);
    LayoutInflater mInflater = LayoutInflater.from(this);

    View mCustomView = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.badge_layout_cartCounter, null);

    mActionBar.setCustomView(mCustomView);
    mActionBar.setDisplayShowCustomEnabled(true);
```

Comment: thanks for your suggestion but my question is where i'm doing wrong in code (please look my java code)

Comment: Ok, so show your xml for badge_layout_cartCounter menu item . And relativelayout too

Comment: can anyone give my answer please i'm really in trouble

Comment: I really recomend you to use toolbar its useful in this cases. But anyway, you mentioned you get getting null on your txtCount . Show please your menu item ,cause if you havent it the  findItem(R.id.badge_layout_cartCounter) will return null

Comment: i have already attach an another layout you can check it out brother(Sir)

Comment: So It's just relativelayout in some xml file , how it can be founded in menu by menu.findItem ?

Comment: yeah sir i want .java code bythe help of this .xml file as i mentioned in my question.i need  correct code which i specified above.(MY CODE) .my first target is just to show view on app what i want to show....

Comment: I edited my answer try this. Also can be helpful http://javatechig.com/android/actionbar-with-custom-view-example-in-android

Comment: sorry for disturbance but have you seen any cart or image which shows your number of item u purchased or number of unread message .so i need that type of layout---http://i.stack.imgur.com/2JxFz.png